# Probability with replacement.

Tags: probability

Inside a box, there are 20 balls, which 5 are red and 15, blue.

I must calculate the probability - with replacement - that is necessary to be drawn, at least, 8 balls until I  get two blue balls.

I thought about using the negative binomial distribution, where the 7th and 8th balls are blue:
$$P(X=7)\cdot P(X=8)$$
where
$$P(X=7)=\binom{7-1}{2-1}\cdot(0.75)^2\cdot(0.25)^5$$
and
$$P(X=8)=\binom{8-1}{2-1}\cdot(0.75)^2\cdot(0.25)^6$$
Is it correct?

Comment: I do not agree with your interpretation.  I interpret it as "*Among the first seven balls exactly one is blue and the eighth ball specifically is also blue.*"  That is exactly what you calculated as $\Pr(X=8)$.  All of this talk about $\Pr(X=7)$ and multiplying $\Pr(X=7)$ and $\Pr(X=8)$ together is unnecessary and incorrect.  Alternatively, if you were instead interested in finding $\Pr(X\geq 8)$ that would be "*Among the first seven, zero or one of the balls were blue*" and that could be answered using binomial distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the negative binomial you get

$$\mathbb{P}[X=x]=\binom{x-1}{2-1}0.75^2\cdot0.25^{x-2}$$

for $x=2,3,4,5,\dots$

Thus

$$\mathbb{P}[X\geq8]=\sum_{x=8}^{\infty}\binom{x-1}{2-1}0.75^2\cdot0.25^{x-2}=$$

$$=1-\sum_{x=2}^{7}\binom{x-1}{2-1}0.75^2\cdot0.25^{x-2}$$